# MVVM has huge code as compared to code behind for the same stuff xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a method to change buttons `BackgroundColor` when each button clicked. This I am able to do easily from code behind.

[image]

Below method using within each button click event

```
void ButtonStyle(Button btn)
{
    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
        if (button.Id == btn.Id)
        {
            button.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
            button.BorderColor = Color.Red;
            button.TextColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            button.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
            button.BorderColor = Color.Gray;
            button.TextColor = Color.Blue;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I comes to using MVVM for the same task, I have huge code to do so

ViewModel class part of code sample code.

```
public class AssignmentDetailViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private Color _bgColorBtn1;
    private Color _bgColorBtn2;
    private Color _bgColorBtn3;

    private Color _txtColorBtn1;
    private Color _txtColorBtn2;
    private Color _txtColorBtn3;

    public Color BgColorBtn1
    {
        get { return _bgColorBtn1; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _bgColorBtn1)
                return;
            _bgColorBtn1 = value;
        }
    }
    public Color BgColorBtn2
    {
        get { return _bgColorBtn2; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _bgColorBtn2)
                return;
            _bgColorBtn2 = value;
        }
    }
    public Color BgColorBtn3
    {
        get { return _bgColorBtn3; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _bgColorBtn3)
                return;
            _bgColorBtn3 = value;
        }
    }


    public Color TextColorBtn1
    {
        get { return _txtColorBtn1; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _txtColorBtn1)
                return;
            _txtColorBtn1 = value;
        }
    }

    public Color TextColorBtn2
    {
        get { return _txtColorBtn2; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _txtColorBtn2)
                return;
            _txtColorBtn1 = value;
        }
    }

    public Color TextColorBtn3
    {
        get { return _txtColorBtn3; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _txtColorBtn3)
                return;
            _txtColorBtn1 = value;
        }
    }


    public Command BtnColorsCmd1
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() => {

                _bgColorBtn1 = Color.White;
                _txtColorBtn1 = Color.Blue;

            });
        }
    }
    public Command BtnColorsCmd2
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() => {

                _bgColorBtn1 = Color.White;
                _txtColorBtn1 = Color.Blue;

            });
        }
    }
    public Command BtnColorsCmd3
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() => {

                _bgColorBtn1 = Color.White;
                _txtColorBtn1 = Color.Blue;

            });
        }
    }
}
```

xaml file

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Spacing="2.5" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="7,6,7,3" Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stackLayou1">
    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding _txtColorBtn1}" BackgroundColor="{Binding _bgColorBtn1}"  x:Name="button1" Text="Assignment"></Button>
    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding _txtColorBtn2}" BackgroundColor="{Binding _bgColorBtn2}"  x:Name="button2" Text="Content"></Button>
    <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding _txtColorBtn3}" BackgroundColor="{Binding _bgColorBtn3}"  x:Name="button3" Text="Review"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Is there any way to reduce this code or other way to do so?

Comment: Instead of using Buttons you can use `ToggleButton`s and define a style with a trigger where you set your colors only if the togglebutton is selected

Comment: This question should be here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why aren't your commands in a list, array or something similar?

Comment: You realize `BtnColorsCmd2` returns the data from 1 instead of 2? Same for `BtnColorsCmd3`.

Comment: In code behind I have condition `btn.Id==button.Id` which don't I can make in viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of the VM in MVVM is to perform operations between your Model (coming from Web Apis, local database or anything else) and your View.

=> DataBinding to display Model informations

=> Command to achieve processes

Here you perform UI operations only that should not take place in your ViewModel in my opinion.

For your need, you should:

-Create a Control in a specific file handling your selection behavior (ContentView or Button directly)

-Define 3 instances in your view

Comment: I didn't get your last two points. Are you telling to add different xaml file and appedn to main xaml file?

Comment: The idea is to create a reusable control (in a separate file) with a  property IsChecked or IsSelected and use it to avoid iteration on all controls like your ButtonStyle method. As suggested, what you want to achieve is a ToggleButton, you can also get one from internet. For example here: https://xamarindevelopervietnam.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/how-to-create-togglebutton-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: If I am not wrong, Toggle buttons are always two on or off with specific UI.

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to the given answer from Rudy Spano you could use a `SetProperty(ref backingField, value)` function comparable to the one defined in this repository (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/master/MvvmHelpers/ObservableObject.cs). 
Of course you can leave outthe validation function and the OnChanged Action. Thus you could reduce the repeated comparison and only have one line per comparison.

Comment: Thakns for your answer. I'll look into it.

Comment: I will also add to the collection of brain dumps... MVVM is a pattern for SOC (separation of concerns) and testability.  While some are non-purists some will also say that if it involves the UI directly (either thru xaml or C#) it could go in the codebehind.  Between the 2 frameworks I have used Prism and Caliburn.Micro both do a fantastic job of reducing your over all code, both have variations of INPC implementation(both do exactly the same thing).. PRISM being one of the first MVVM/MVP frameworks circa early 2000s.  Each have their own, idiosyncrasies for usage.